# Is the following DateFormat able to generate locale indepdent date string

Tags: java, android

My ideal way, of having a locale independent date string, is by using the following code

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

which means, if I run the above code in a Arabic device, or a United States device, both will generate same string.

For the above case, `dateFormat.format(date)` will produce **Dec 26, 2015**.

I came across a legacy code, which is using the following way to generate locale independent date string.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Will the above code be truly locale independent. Will it "mistakenly" generate string like **26 Dec, 2015**?

I wrote a simple code, to test both on Windows and Android device.

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    DateFormat dateFormat0 = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH);
    DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    if (false == dateFormat0.format(date).equals(dateFormat1.format(date))) {
        throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("Opps");
    }
}
```

No exception was being thrown.

I was wondering, can we assume that `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH)` will generate same date string too across different devices? Is there any edge case I didn't handle?

Comment: The locale is fixed in your code, but the _time zone_ isn't; `SimpleDateFormat` will use the platform default time zone unless you set it explicitly. You can set the time zone to a fixed value (e.g. UTC) using [`setTimeZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)).

Answer (score 1):

Using `"MMM dd, yyyy"`you retain control of the output, where by using the integer constant `DateFormat.DEFAULT` you are leaving it up to the locale definitions for the platform. They *should* be identical across these platforms for any given locale, but there really are no guarantee.

The `DateFormat.DEFAULT` parameter is only useful if you work with different Locales, as it'll allow `DateFormat` to create the proper localized date string.

Example:

```
DateFormat dfEn = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat dfFr = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.FRENCH);
DateFormat dfGe = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.GERMAN);

System.out.println("ENGLISH: " + dfEn.format(date));
System.out.println("FRENCH : " + dfFr.format(date));
System.out.println("GERMAN : " + dfGe.format(date));
```

prints:

```
ENGLISH: Dec 26, 2015
FRENCH : 26 déc. 2015
GERMAN : 26.12.2015
```

Answer (score -1):

I you want to be sure that the rendered date looks always the same it's the best choice to define the format explicitely as you did in your first code snippet:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

The given locale here does not define the formatting but the wording to be used, here the name of the month is in english ("Dec"), rather than e.g. in german ("Dez").

Comment: Are you able to produce case where `DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, Locale.ENGLISH);` isn't platform independent?

Comment: Why should I try? I am not an academic researcher. I am just a programmer, and when I have a solution, why should I try to proove that another solution might be also good or not?